# The order of $P(K)/P^+(K)$ in a quadratic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a quadratic extension.
Let $P(K)$ be the group of principle fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$.
Let $P^+(K)$ be the subgroup of principle fractional ideals with generator with positive norm over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm interested in the order of $P(K)/P^+(K)$.

If $\mathcal{O}_K$ contains a unit of norm $-1$ then any priciple fractional ideal has a generator with positive norm and thus $P(K)=P^+(K)$.
What if there are no such units? We still have $I^2 \in P^+(K)$ for any $I \in P(K)$, but do we have $|P(K)/P^+(K)|=2$ (that's my guess)?

Comment: I do not think that your condition is sufficient enough to deduce that the order is $2$. But certainly it has exponent $=2$.

Comment: @awllower: Is it a finite group?

Comment: I am also wondering. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(K)\ne P^{+}(K)$, then there exists $\lambda_0\in K^*$ such that $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/\mathbb Q}(\lambda_0)<0$. Suppose we are in this situation. 
For all $\lambda\in K^*$, either $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/\mathbb Q}(\lambda)>0$ and 
$\lambda O_K\in P^+(K)$, or $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/\mathbb Q}(\lambda)<0$. In the latter case $\lambda=\lambda_0 u$ with $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/\mathbb Q}(u)>0$. So $P(K)/P^+(K)$ is generated by the class of $\lambda_0 O_K$. As $(\lambda_0 O_K)^2\in P^+(K)$, the conclusion is $P(K)/P^+(K)$ always has at most two elements.

Comment: I must admit that I was surprised by this awesome yet simple answer.